# Динамический рендеринг частичных представлений

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor

Добрй день. Столкнулся с такой проблемой в Asp.Net Core MVC.

*Как сделать динамический рендер частичного представления в моем случае `GetOrders()`, так чтобы `index()` не нужно было обновлять, чтоб обновлялся только `GetOrders()` при применении фильтров?*

Мне нужно рендерить частичное представление `GetOrders()`, которое представляет из себя таблицу. Рендерить нужно ее в обычном представлении `index()` без обновления самой страницы `index()`, например как это делается с главной страницой `@RenderBody()`.

[image: Пример @RenderBody]

Вот так выглядит мой макет:
[image: Мой макет]
Основная часть это `Index()` метод в котором расположены фильтры для таблицы. И частичное представление это таблица выделенная красным квадратом `GetOrders()`. Мне необходимо передавать данные из формы фильтров `Index()` в метод `GetOrders()` и получать отфильтрованный вариант.
Вот таким образом я пытался это реализовать:

**Контроллер**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var selectValues = await _orderServices.GetDistinct();
            ViewBag.SelectProductsName = new SelectList(selectValues.Name, "Name");
            ViewBag.SelectNumber = new SelectList(selectValues.Number, "Number");
            ViewBag.SelectProviderName = new SelectList(selectValues.ProviderName, "ProviderName");
            ViewBag.SelectProductUnit = new SelectList(selectValues.Unit, "Unit");
            ViewBag.DatePast = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
            ViewBag.DateNow = DateTime.Now;
            return View();
        }

public async Task<ActionResult> GetOrders(DateTime past, DateTime now, string[] name, string[] unit, string[] number, string[] providerName)
        {
            var filter = new OrdersFilterViewModel { DatePast = past, DateNow = now, Name = name, Number = number, Unit = unit, ProviderName = providerName };
            var result = await _orderServices.GetOrdersTable(filter);
            return PartialView(result.OrderBy(o => o.Number));
        }
```

**Основное представление Index()**
*Я скрыл некоторые ненужные детали*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Частичное представление GetOrders()**
*Я скрыл некоторые ненужные детали*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Делаю я это с целью того чтобы фильтры не сбрасывались при применении.**

Comment: вопрос то в чем?

Comment: Как сделать динамический рендер частичного представления ```GetOrders()```, так чтобы ```index()``` не нужно было обновлять?

Comment: ajax использовать?

Comment: Ajax не работает. На хабре смотрел сказали что от него отказались. так что хз

Comment: Походу самому fetch и писать нужно

Comment: От ajax не просто отказаться, он ведь в каждом браузере присутсвует. Тот же fetch - по сути надстройка над ajax

Comment: Я попробовал его юзать через ```using(Ajax)``` он его тупо не видит